# Porting C++ OpenGL Game to iPad

Tags: c++, objective-c, ipad, porting

We have a game, developed in C++ and OpenGL for Windows and Mac.

Now we want to port the game to iPad. Is there a better way than writing the entire program in Objective-C to make our game work on iPad?

Now I am an iPhone/iPad noob, so pardon if the question is dumb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to write only a small part in Obj-C that deals directly with iOS(creating a gl surface, input etc). Rest should work fine. You just need to make sure you will be using only the subset of OpenGL that is in OpenGL ES.

Comment: so the entire gaming logic can be in C++ itself?

Comment: @andy Yes.  Over 90% of the code in my iOS applications is C++.  You will need to have some files that use the `.mm` file extension for Objective-C++ that will let you work with both Objective-C and C++ in the same file in order to use the Objective-C system libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I hear [DragonFire SDK](http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/) lets you develop in C++ for iOS, on Windows.